# Whole listview gets duplicated

Tags: android, listview

I've a listview which shows values from web service. Its fine when it loads the listview. But when I click on any item to open a new fragment (which shows details of the item) and get back to the same listview, its items doubles everytime. For example, if I have (in original) 5 items in total. Then when I get back from the fragment, the total count will be 10, then 15 and so on. It means the app is adding all items again and again. I searched for the solution and did what were the general solution like `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but its still gets duplicated. If anyone can show me the problem, I would be grateful.

```css
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Model> mListData = new ArrayList<Model>();



    public CustomListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Model> mListData) {
        super(mContext, resource, mListData);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListData = mListData;
    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<Model> mListData) {
        this.mListData = mListData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

            v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            holder.custname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);
            holder.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.staffname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.staff_name);
            holder.time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.service = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.service);
            holder.refid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.refid);


            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }




        final Model item = mListData.get(position);

        holder.custname.setText(item.getCustname());
        holder.date.setText(item.getDate());
        holder.staffname.setText(item.getStaffname());
        holder.time.setText(item.getTime());
        holder.service.setText(item.getService());
        holder.refid.setText(item.getRefid());


        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView custname, date, staffname, time, service, refid;
    }
}
```

```html
public class ListFrag extends Fragment{

    private SwipeMenuListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private CShowProgress cShowProgress;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private String uid, bookingId;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String BOOKED_LIST = "http://192.168.220.13/android/showbookinglist";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfrag, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        listView = (SwipeMenuListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
        cShowProgress = CShowProgress.getInstance();

        


        fetchDetails();

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String a = arrayList.get(i).getCustname();
                String b = arrayList.get(i).getStaffname();
                String c = arrayList.get(i).getService();
                String d = arrayList.get(i).getDate();
                String e = arrayList.get(i).getTime();
                String f = arrayList.get(i).getRefid();
                String g = arrayList.get(i).getEmail();
                String h = arrayList.get(i).getServprice();
                String j = arrayList.get(i).getSpeclprice();
                String k = arrayList.get(i).getStatus();


                db.addDetails(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, k);

                DetailsView details = new DetailsView();
                ((Bookings)getActivity()).replaceFragment(details);
            }
        });

       
    }

    private void fetchDetails() {

        cShowProgress.showProgress(getActivity());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BOOKED_LIST,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        cShowProgress.hideProgress();

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Model model = new Model();
                                model.setCustname(obj.getString("customername"));
                                model.setDate(obj.getString("staffdate"));
                                model.setStaffname(obj.getString("staffname")+"(Staff)");
                                model.setTime(obj.getString("stafftime"));
                                model.setService(obj.getString("servicename"));
                                model.setRefid(obj.getString("booking_referenceid"));
                                model.setEmail(obj.getString("customeremail"));
                                model.setServprice(obj.getString("serviceprice"));
                                model.setSpeclprice(obj.getString("specialprice"));
                                model.setStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                                model.setBookid(obj.getString("bookingid"));

                                arrayList.add(model);
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();






                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("spaid", "145");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change it as.. B'coz you are adding the elements in previously created list.. So you have to clear it.

```
 private void fetchDetails() {

if(arrayList!=null )arrayList.clear(); // this line

        cShowProgress.showProgress(getActivity());
```

Comment: Clearing the arraylist makes the best solution. Thanks so much @saurabh
Also, thanks to all of you for your replies.

Comment: I did everything to find out i had this issue, you sir, amazing

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that when you get back to the fragment it is recreated and **onViewCreated** is called again. From there you call again **fetchDetails()** and then your are adding the whole List for a second time to the adapter. So you can clear the list before **fetchDetails()** or just if you have to fetch them again.

Answer (score 0):

change your try - catch block of onResponse method by below.

```
       try {
                   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                   arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                   for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                   {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         Model model = new Model();
                            model.setCustname(obj.getString("customername"));
                            model.setDate(obj.getString("staffdate"));
                            model.setStaffname(obj.getString("staffname")+"(Staff)");
                            model.setTime(obj.getString("stafftime"));
                            model.setService(obj.getString("servicename"));
                            model.setRefid(obj.getString("booking_referenceid"));
                            model.setEmail(obj.getString("customeremail"));
                            model.setServprice(obj.getString("serviceprice"));
                            model.setSpeclprice(obj.getString("specialprice"));
                            model.setStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                            model.setBookid(obj.getString("bookingid"));

                            arrayList.add(model);
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not clearing the arrayList. Due to this every time that you construct the array and the adapter, you are adding the elements into an array that already has elements.

That why you have 5, then 10, then 15 and so on..

Clear the array before adding new elements

```
arrayList.clear();
```

Or program another strategy like:

- Not populate the array every time you return to the fragment.
- Check if he element existe before add it into the array.